# How to escape single quote in insert statements using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to insert data into a redshift table using python in aws glue job . Some of the columns in my test table(which is loaded froma csv) has single quotes (like Carl's) and when i run the script the insert statement is prepared as 
Insert into Details values ('1','Mark Jason','Carl's', 'NY')
and the code fails detecting extra s.

I have tried to use parameterized statements but not able to get the correct results. Please help on where am i going wrong.

```
import pg8000
from datetime import datetime
conn = pg8000.connect(user = 'xxx', password = 'xx', host = 'xxx.redshift.amazonaws.com',  port = 5000, database = 'xx')
cursor = conn.cursor()

currentDT = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
dest_table = "detail"
stg_table = "test"
dest_columns=['id','Name','Store','Location','Insert_time']
stg_columns = ['id','Name','Store','Location']
add_column=currentDT

dest_col_str = ""
for i in dest_columns:
    dest_col_str  += i+", "
dest_col_str  = dest_col_str [:-2]


data = "select distinct * from "+stg_table
cursor.execute(data)
List = cursor.fetchall()

for i in range(len(List)):
    e = List[i]

source_data = ""
        for x in e:
            if str(x) == '':
                source_data += 'null'
            elif type(x) == datetime or type(x) == str or type(x) == unicode:
                source_data += "'"+str(x)+"'"
            else:
                source_data += str(x)
            source_data+=','

query="INSERT INTO  "+dest_table+"("+dest_col_str +" , "+add_column+") values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"

data=source_data+add_column          
cursor.execute(query,data)
cursor.execute("COMMIT;")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backslash before 's' as follows.

```
 ('1','Mark Jason','Carl\'s', 'NY')
```

it will solve your issue.

Comment: Hi Yogesh, i am reading the data from another table, so i need to automate the code, should replacing ' with \' would work?